# Using WIQL, how do you query VSTS Work Items on System.Tags

Tags: c#, azure-devops, wiql, azure-devops-rest-api

This is not an on-premise install, just VSTS.  I'm new to working with the VSTS REST API and WIQL.  I am trying to run a query that filters my work items on `System.Tags = 'User Generated'`.  When I retrieve my Work Item, I can see in the JSON:

```
System.Tags : "User Generated"
```

I am using the following guide to build my query and have everything working except when I try to filter on Tags.  I have tried `[System.Tags] Contains ('User Generated')`, etc.  Nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

[VSTS WIQL Reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/wit/wiql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so right after I give up and post, I figured it out.  I was using Contains incorrectly.  I had the filter in parenthesis.  Both of the following examples work now.

```
Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State], [System.Tags]
From WorkItems
Where [State] <> 'Closed'
 AND [State] <> 'Removed'
 AND [Tags] Contains 'User Generated'
 AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story'
 order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc
```

Or this:

```
Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State]
From WorkItems
Where [State] <> 'Closed'
 AND [State] <> 'Removed'
 AND [System.Tags] Contains 'User Generated'
 AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story'
 order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc
```

Comment: The easiest way to debug and create queries is to create what you want in visual studio query builder and save it to your desktop. Open in notepad and copy...